# All accounts lost on each reboot

Tags: macbook-pro, user-account, reboot, single-user

I recently purchased a used 2015 MacBook Pro. The machine is in excellent condition, and they did a factory reset before I took the device.

Every time I shut down the machine, all of the users have disappeared and only the default "test" account appears. I have to log into single user mode, run `/sbin/mount -uw /` and `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` so I can go through the device set up.

This is frustrating, as I have to go through this process to create a new admin user just to use the device. Once new user setup is complete, I can log out and all of the other users appear.

Any ideas on what is causing this or how I can fix it?

Comment: Since this is a new system for you, I would boot into Internet Recovery (`Command-Option-R`) and then do a clean installation - wipe the drive first using Disk Utility.